# Representing dependencies file syntax

Tags: syntax, dependencies, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm looking for a simple way to represent simple dependencies in a file. Preferably I'd like to use some format with a syntax already defined (e.g. JSON, YAML, etc). I'm leaning towards [graphviz](http://graphviz.org)'s dot syntax

```
digraph {
    A -> B;
    A -> C;
    B -> D;
}
```

Are there any other ways to do this?

This will be for user's to write simple dependencies in and parsed by an application.

Answer (score 0):

The [NetworkX](http://networkx.lanl.gov) graph library has a number of [standard formats](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/readwrite.html) for data files which are worth checking out.